# JAXB class from .XSD file Schema

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using sts to generate Java classes using Jaxb2 maven plugin, I used mvn clean compile -e to show the errors and this what I get

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: InvalidRegex: Pattern value '[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-\+]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+
)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '\-'
.' at column '{2}'.
```

Any suggestion or solution 
Thanks

Comment: The error explicitly tells you what is wrong and how to fix. You have a invalid regexp, how to fix is also in the error msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the '-' at the end of each part of the pattern.
By adding  the escape character '/' .
Thanks